# Como sobrebor um loader por cima das divs no angular2

Tags: css, front-end, angular, webdesign

estou tentando implementar um loader em um projeto angular enquanto solicita a requisição. mas não estou consseguindo posiciona-lo no centro da tela sobrepondo as outras divs... olha como ele esta ficando, só aparece uma ponta dele na imagem e em cima sem sobrepor o conteudo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

o loader que estou usando é esse https://codepen.io/WebSonata/pen/bRaONB
abaixo segue o codigo css e depois do html do meu projeto:

o css:

```
.row{
    margin-top:50px;
  }

  .img{
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }

  .inputfile {
      width: 0.1px;
      height: 0.1px;
      opacity: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: -1;
  }
  .inputfile + label {
      font-size: 1.25em;
      font-weight: 700;
      color: white;
      background-color: black;
      display: inline-block;
  }

  .inputfile:focus + label,
  .inputfile + label:hover {
      background-color: red;
  }
  .inputfile + label {
      cursor: pointer; /* "hand" cursor */
  }
  .inputfile:focus + label {
      outline: 1px dotted #000;
      outline: -webkit-focus-ring-color auto 5px;
  }
  .inputfile + label * {
      pointer-events: none;
  }

// --------- a parte do loader é essa
#preloader {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#loader {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: -75px 0 0 -75px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 3px solid transparent;
    border-top-color: #9370DB;
    -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
    animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}
#loader:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    right: 5px;
    bottom: 5px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 3px solid transparent;
    border-top-color: #BA55D3;
    -webkit-animation: spin 3s linear infinite;
    animation: spin 3s linear infinite;
}
#loader:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    left: 15px;
    right: 15px;
    bottom: 15px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 3px solid transparent;
    border-top-color: #FF00FF;
    -webkit-animation: spin 1.5s linear infinite;
    animation: spin 1.5s linear infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    0%   {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
@keyframes spin {
    0%   {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

e o html:

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>

<div id="preloader" *ngIf="loader">
        <div id="loader"></div>
      </div>


      <div><div class="container-fluid">
    <form novalidate [formGroup]="formulario" (ngSubmit)="cadastrar()">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-5">
            <div class="card card-user">
                <div class="image">
                    <div *ngIf="!data.image">
                        <img [src]="nomeFoto" class="img" />
                      </div>
                      <div *ngIf="click">
                        <img-cropper #cropper [image]="data" [settings]="cropperSettings" class="img"></img-cropper>
                      </div>
                      <input type="file" name="file" id="custom-input" class="btn btn-primary" accept="image/*" (change)="fileChangeListener($event)">
                </div>
            </div>
     <div class="card">
                <div class="header">
                    <h4 class="title">Termos de Uso</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="content">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-7">
            <div class="card" style="padding: 30px;">
                <div class="header">
                    <h4 class="title">Cadastro</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="content">

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Nome</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome" formControlName="nome">
                                    <small *ngIf="!formulario.get('nome').valid && formulario.get('nome').touched" class="form-text text-danger">Campo Obrigatorio</small>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-7">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Sobrenome</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control border-input" placeholder="Sobrenome"  formControlName="sobrenome">
                                    <small *ngIf="!formulario.get('sobrenome').valid && formulario.get('sobrenome').touched" class="form-text text-danger">Campo Obrigatorio</small>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Email</label>
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control border-input" placeholder="Email" formControlName="email">
                                    <small *ngIf="!formulario.get('email').valid && formulario.get('email').touched" class="form-text text-danger">Email Invalido</small>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Repita o Email</label>
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control border-input" placeholder="Repita o Email" formControlName="email2">
                                    <small *ngIf="!formulario.get('email2').valid && formulario.get('email2').touched" class="form-text text-danger">Os emails nao sao iguais</small>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Senha</label>
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control border-input" placeholder="Senha" formControlName="senha">
                                    <small *ngIf="!formulario.get('senha').valid && formulario.get('senha').touched" class="form-text text-danger">A senha deve ter pelo menos 6 caracteres</small>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Repita a Senha</label>
                                        <input type="password" class="form-control border-input" placeholder="Repita a Senha" formControlName="senha2">
                                        <small *ngIf="!formulario.get('senha2').valid && formulario.get('senha2').touched" class="form-text text-danger">As senhas nao sao iguais</small>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Sobre Mim</label>
                                    <textarea rows="5" class="form-control border-input" placeholder="Escreva um pouco sobre você" formControlName="sobreMim">
Oh so, your weak rhyme
You doubt I'll bother, reading into it
I'll probably won't, left to my own devices
But that's the difference in our opinions.</textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-fill btn-wd"  >Cadastrar</button>
                        </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </form>

</div>

<!-- Modals -->

  <!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" #abrirModalEmailJaExiste [hidden]="true" data-target="#emailJaExisteModal">
    Launch demo modal
  </button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="emailJaExisteModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="emailJaExisteModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="emailJaExisteModalLabel">{{tituloModal}}</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        <p>{{mensagemModal}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Troque o `position: relative` do `#preloader` por `position: fixed`:

```
#preloader {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

O `position: fixed` posiciona a `div` em relação ao documento todo.

**Exemplo:**

```css
.row{
    margin-top:50px;
  }

  .img{
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }

  .inputfile {
      width: 0.1px;
      height: 0.1px;
      opacity: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: -1;
  }
  .inputfile + label {
      font-size: 1.25em;
      font-weight: 700;
      color: white;
      background-color: black;
      display: inline-block;
  }

  .inputfile:focus + label,
  .inputfile + label:hover {
      background-color: red;
  }
  .inputfile + label {
      cursor: pointer; /* "hand" cursor */
  }
  .inputfile:focus + label {
      outline: 1px dotted #000;
      outline: -webkit-focus-ring-color auto 5px;
  }
  .inputfile + label * {
      pointer-events: none;
  }


#preloader {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#loader {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: -75px 0 0 -75px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 3px solid transparent;
    border-top-color: #9370DB;
    -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
    animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}
#loader:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    right: 5px;
    bottom: 5px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 3px solid transparent;
    border-top-color: #BA55D3;
    -webkit-animation: spin 3s linear infinite;
    animation: spin 3s linear infinite;
}
#loader:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    left: 15px;
    right: 15px;
    bottom: 15px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 3px solid transparent;
    border-top-color: #FF00FF;
    -webkit-animation: spin 1.5s linear infinite;
    animation: spin 1.5s linear infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    0%   {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
@keyframes spin {
    0%   {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<app-navbar></app-navbar>

<div id="preloader" *ngIf="loader">
        <div id="loader"></div>
      </div>


      <div><div class="container-fluid">
    <form novalidate [formGroup]="formulario" (ngSubmit)="cadastrar()">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-5">
            <div class="card card-user">
                <div class="image">
                    <div *ngIf="!data.image">
                        <img [src]="nomeFoto" class="img" />
                      </div>
                      <div *ngIf="click">
                        <img-cropper #cropper [image]="data" [settings]="cropperSettings" class="img"></img-cropper>
                      </div>
                      <input type="file" name="file" id="custom-input" class="btn btn-primary" accept="image/*" (change)="fileChangeListener($event)">
                </div>
            </div>
     <div class="card">
                <div class="header">
                    <h4 class="title">Termos de Uso</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="content">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-7">
            <div class="card" style="padding: 30px;">
                <div class="header">
                    <h4 class="title">Cadastro</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="content">

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Nome</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome" formControlName="nome">
                                    <small *ngIf="!formulario.get('nome').valid && formulario.get('nome').touched" class="form-text text-danger">Campo Obrigatorio</small>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-7">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Sobrenome</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control border-input" placeholder="Sobrenome"  formControlName="sobrenome">
                                    <small *ngIf="!formulario.get('sobrenome').valid && formulario.get('sobrenome').touched" class="form-text text-danger">Campo Obrigatorio</small>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Email</label>
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control border-input" placeholder="Email" formControlName="email">
                                    <small *ngIf="!formulario.get('email').valid && formulario.get('email').touched" class="form-text text-danger">Email Invalido</small>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Repita o Email</label>
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control border-input" placeholder="Repita o Email" formControlName="email2">
                                    <small *ngIf="!formulario.get('email2').valid && formulario.get('email2').touched" class="form-text text-danger">Os emails nao sao iguais</small>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Senha</label>
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control border-input" placeholder="Senha" formControlName="senha">
                                    <small *ngIf="!formulario.get('senha').valid && formulario.get('senha').touched" class="form-text text-danger">A senha deve ter pelo menos 6 caracteres</small>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Repita a Senha</label>
                                        <input type="password" class="form-control border-input" placeholder="Repita a Senha" formControlName="senha2">
                                        <small *ngIf="!formulario.get('senha2').valid && formulario.get('senha2').touched" class="form-text text-danger">As senhas nao sao iguais</small>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Sobre Mim</label>
                                    <textarea rows="5" class="form-control border-input" placeholder="Escreva um pouco sobre você" formControlName="sobreMim">
Oh so, your weak rhyme
You doubt I'll bother, reading into it
I'll probably won't, left to my own devices
But that's the difference in our opinions.</textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-fill btn-wd"  >Cadastrar</button>
                        </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </form>

</div>

<!-- Modals -->

  <!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" #abrirModalEmailJaExiste [hidden]="true" data-target="#emailJaExisteModal">
    Launch demo modal
  </button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="emailJaExisteModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="emailJaExisteModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="emailJaExisteModalLabel">{{tituloModal}}</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        <p>{{mensagemModal}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: opa, muito obrigado